# How do i include and overloading function inside an overload function

Tags: c++

Here is mine Full code. Am trying to Include inpatient if the case is one(1) but some highlight show that is wrong. is there anyhow to fix this if not can you please tell me another way to do it as long as it include inpatient if one(1) is Entered

```
void selection(int &);
void processor(int &);
void inPatient(double &, double &, double &, double &);

int main()
{
    int selected, include;
    double numberOfDays, dailyRate, chargesForHospital, hospitalMedicationCharge;

    selection(selected);
    validate(selected, selected);
    processor(selected);

    system("pause");
    return(0);
}

void selection(int & selectedOption)
{
    cout << "\nEnter Selection: ";
    cin >> selectedOption;
}

void processor(int & selectedOption)
{
    switch(selectedOption)
    {
        case 1:
             inPatient(umberOfDays, dailyRate, chargesForHospital, hospitalMedicationCharge);
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "out-Pat" << endl;
            break;
        default :
            cout << "Nothing Selected" << endl;
            break;
    }
}

void inPatient(double & numberOfDays, double & dailyRate, double & chargesForHospital, double & hospitalMedicationCharge)
{
    cout << "The number of days spent in the hospital: ";
    cin >> numberOfDays;
    cout << "The daily rate: ";
    cin >> dailyRate;
    cout << "Charges for hospital services (lab tests, etc.): ";
    cin >> chargesForHospital;
    cout << "Hospital medication charges: ";
    cin >> hospitalMedicationCharge;
}
```

Comment: whats the right way to include patric into name

Comment: There are so many errors here, post some code that actually compiles.

Comment: Are you sure you know what overloading functions means? As there are no overloads in your example, although they could be elsewhere.

Comment: There is no overloading in your new code either.

Comment: how do i make were it say case 1: "inPatient.." work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of errors in the code that you posted, but I'll try to address your immediate problem. You're trying to call a function like this:

```
patric(int & gender, int & age)
```

but that's more like a function declaration. To actually call the function, you pass in arguments but omit the type, like this:

```
patric(someGender, someAge);
```

The `int &` in the declaration says that the parameters are references to values of type `int`, so the values you pass when you call `patric` should be of type `int`.

Also, you say that `patric` is overloaded. That means that there are several versions of the function, each with different parameter lists. So, maybe there's the one above as well as one that doesn't take any values -- maybe their declarations look like this, respectively:

```
void patric(int &gender, int &age);
void patric(void);
```

Given that, if you wanted to call the second version, you'd just call it:

```
patric();
```

(The `void` in the parameter list in the second version means that the function doesn't take any parameters. The `void` before the function name means that it doesn't return anything.)

Note also that you need a semicolon (`;`) following the function call.

Comment: can u look over it again?